# Canvas.Move doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

```
def moveR(amount):
   global x
   global y
   x = x+amount
   can.itemconfig(player, image = playerImageL)
   can.move("player", x, y)
   root.update()

##SETTING##

can = Canvas(width = 850, height = 550, bg = "black")
can.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

player = can.create_image(x, y, image = playerImageL, anchor = NW)
root.update()
```

Hey, i am trying to create a mini game using tkinter and canvas however the move command doesn't work. As you see the SETTING is the setup later in the code i am calling

```
moveR(100)
```

however it doesn't work and seems to completly destroy my sprite/image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text `"player"` and variable `player` are two different things.

Use variable `player` in `move()`

```
can.move(player, x, y)
```

BTW: you don't need `itemconfig()`

Comment: Oh by the way the itemconfig() is for different states of the player.

Answer (score 1):

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  To make the code easily verifiable, use something like a rectangle instead of an image.  (Your code fails the same for any item.)

`Canvas.move(item, delta_x, delta_y)` moves the item a given x and y amount.  It does the x + dy calculation itself, so you should not.  If you want to move to a given position, use `Canvas.coords(item, x0, y0, x1, y1)`.  If the size of the new bounding box is different from what it was, it will also change the shape. The following example uses both methods.  As a bonus, it also shows how to use `root.after` to make repeated changes.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
can = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=500)
can.pack()
rec = can.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='red')
def rmove():
    box = can.bbox(rec)
    if box[0] < 700:
        can.move(rec, 100, 30)
        root.after(1000, rmove)
    else:
        can.coords(rec, 0, 400, 50, 500)  # position with new shape
root.after(1000, rmove)
root.mainloop()
```